# Django: Getting path of module being imported from views.py

Tags: python, django, path

I have been trying to figure out how to consistently get an absolute path to the directory of one of my modules so that I can open files in that same directory, regardless of whether the module is being run directly or being imported from somewhere else.

Am I just misunderstanding the way os.path and _ *file* _ work, or is there some quirk in Django that is causing this?

**views.py:**

```
def pathtest(request):
    return HttpResponse(mymodule.getpath())
```

**mymodule.py:**

```
def getpath():
    return os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
/home/user/projects/myproject/mymodule/mymodule.py
```

**Actual Output:**

```
/home/user/projects/myproject/views.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do this?

**mymodule.py**:

```
def getpath():
    os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: This seems to work! It gives me the "expected output" from above.If you wouldn't mind, could you please explain the difference as far as why the code above does not give me what I expected and this one does? Earlier I tried dirname(abspath(__file__)) which didn't work, yet abspath(dirname(__file__)) does. What is the difference conceptually? Thank you so much.

Comment: From what I understand, the abspath() method cleans up any relative paths and gives you a clean, "absolutized" version of the path, where dirname, may still contain relative paths in it.

Answer (score 2):

this is not about Django, os module is a python built-in.

You do not have to implement the getpath function in the mymodule module, you can solve this just by import the module and get the __file__ attribute from it.

```
import mymodule
import os
print os.path.abspath(mymodule.__file__)
```

should work just fine

Comment: The getpath function is just an example I wrote to illustrate my problem. I need the path from within the mymodule module so that I can open files from within the same directory, however because mymodule is being called/included from views.py it is giving me the path to views.py instead.